# how to connect bubble and S3 via api for video?

Tags: amazon-s3, video, bubble.io

I am trying to use Bubble as a front end with a video player plugin, AWS S3 to store video content and an API to connect the two. I have created a bucket and an API on AWS. However, there isn't a video type on the data type option of Bubble's API plugin. So, I am not sure if this is even possible. I am looking for advice on how to make this setup work.

Thanks.